# Erro ao executar um INSERT em uma visão

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou com essa tabela

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CNPJ          | char(14)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| fkusuario     | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| DataCadastro  | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Razao         | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Operadora     | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Linhas        | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Classificacao | varchar(3)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Vigencia      | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mesesContrato | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Fidelidade    | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ValorGasto    | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| FixoEmpresa   | varchar(17)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Gestor        | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Celular       | varchar(17)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| FixoGestor    | varchar(17)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Email         | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Obs           | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

A partir dela criei uma view idêntica porem sem o campo `fkusuario` e estou tentando fazer um insert nessa view

```
insert into checagens_sem_fk values('8425787107104','2019-04-16', 'REDECARD S A', 'VIVO', '23', 'A', '2018-05-15', '12', 'Não Fidelizado B','850', '994901415', 'BRUNO', '15997677764', '1532594563', 'suporte@comercio.com', 'teste');
```

Porém ela me resulta um erro:

> Error Code: 1423. Field of view 'global.checagens_sem_fk' underlying table doesn't have a default value

O que poderia ser? eu posso fazer um insert em uma view? ou será que é por conta de retirar a chave estrangeira.

**EDIT com a criação da view**

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CNPJ          | char(14)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DataCadastro  | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Razao         | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Operadora     | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Linhas        | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Classificacao | varchar(3)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Vigencia      | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mesesContrato | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Fidelidade    | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ValorGasto    | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| FixoEmpresa   | varchar(17)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Gestor        | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Celular       | varchar(17)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| FixoGestor    | varchar(17)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Email         | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Obs           | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Pode colocar o script de criação da view na pergunta?

Comment: Este erro costuma ocorrer quando se usa um `insert` sem os nomes das colunas e uma das colunas não informadas não tem um valor default definido.

Comment: @vnbrs Editei a pergunta

Comment: O  view é só uma projeção dos dados  da tabela que ele representa. Quando você insere em um view editável na verdade a inserção está ocorrendo na tabela que dá origem aos dados do view e no seu caso há uma chave estrangeira `fkusuario INT NOT NULL` que exige um valor e essa chave não referenciada pelo view o que resultará em um erro toda vez que um `INSERT` for feito na visão.

Comment: @AugustoVasques entendi, terei que procurar outra alternativa então, obrigado ^^

Answer (score 2):

Os bancos de dados geralmente não permitem fazer updates em views, em alguns até se pode configurar isso na criação da view mas vai muito de banco para banco, como views não passam de uma seleção de várias tabelas fica quase impossível cascatear os dados corretamente em todas, como por exemplo nas quais possuem sequências. 
Se lhe servir de ajuda deixo este link que explica bem o caso:

> https://www.w3resource.com/sql/update-views/sql-update-views.php

Outra boa opção é ler a documentação do banco em relação às views.

Abraço.

Comment: Interessante, mas no meu caso é um INSERT como o @AugustoVasques citou é por conta da chave estrangeira eu achei q uma view se tornava uma tabela virtual mas é simplesmente uma projeção .